# How to calculate area of multipart polygon in R

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, area

I'm having trouble calculating in R the area of an imported shapefile that has a multipart polygon (one feature containing two separate polygons).  I noticed that ArcMap gave me a different value for the area of a shapefile than `raster::area`. To figure out which program was giving me the correct area, I broke the shapefile into single parts and recalculated the area of the two separate polygons:

```
library(raster)

> single_part <- shapefile("../Desktop/test/test_sp.shp")
> area(single_part)
[1] 575924.0 433409.8
> sum(area(single_part))
[1] 1009334
> 
> multi_part <-  shapefile("../Desktop/test/test_mp.shp")
> area(multi_part)
[1] 1018390
```

I realize now that I know about this problem, I should always break up polygon feature classes into single parts, but does anyone know how `raster::area` calculates the area of multipart polygons?  I also tried using `rgeos::gArea` but got the same result. Is there a way to calculate the area of multipart polygons in R?

I'd  love to know, because they're pretty common and I'm trying to switch from doing all my analyses in ArcMap to R.

In case it's helpful, here's an image of the shapefile:
[multipart poly shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1HcH.png)

EDIT ADDED 9/21/2018 -------------------------------------------------------

Here's a [link to the shapefile test_mp.shp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BmP_KPHTrik5ZywoM74znNfR9FTgD2dg/view?usp=sharing)

From what I can tell, it seems like the problem stems from how R (vs. ArcMap) interprets the holes.  See the difference between the [ArcMap display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKFto.png) and the [R display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIo6h.png). For some reason R is filling in those holes as part of the shapefile, which must be the reason that I'm getting different calculations for the area. Is there something wrong with the shapefile, or how I'm importing it?

Comment: See if this answer is useful, either with the `byid=TRUE` flag or the splitting method. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200420/calculate-area-for-each-polygon-in-r

Comment: @Anonymouscoward No, I'd read that answer already, and it covers a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your object named 'multi_part' has only one (multi?) polygon, as `area` returns a single value. I illustrate here how to investigate what you are after:

```
library(raster)
d <- getData('GADM', country='Isle of Man', level=0)

area(d)
[1] 579672897
```

Split into 4 polygons (islands)

```
dd <- disaggregate(d)
a <- area(dd)
a
[1]     19424.12   2705442.41     25629.79 576922400.90
sum(a)
[1] 579672897
```

The same area, and there is no reason why they would be different. Except perhaps if there is confusion with polygon holes. It is difficult to comment without your data.

You can write these objects to disk (see below) and see what ArcGIS gives you as area (but note that this example uses lon/lat coordinates, I am not sure if ArcGIS can compute areas on those).

```
shapefile(d, "man.shp")
```

Here is a case with and without a hole:

```
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
p2 <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))

# two (overlapping) polygons (no hole)   
pol1 <- spPolygons(p1, p2, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
# single polygon with hole
pol2 <- spPolygons(list(p1, p2), crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")

a <- area(pol1) / 10e+9
b <- area(pol2) / 10e+9

a
#[1] 10925   800
sum(a)
#[1] 11725
a[1]-a[2]
#[1] 10125
```

`b` matches `a[1] - a[2]`, as expected

```
b
#[1] 10125
```

I get exactly the same results with ArcGIS, using "calculate geometry" for a field in the attribute tables.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an answer! Yes, the object multi_part just has one multipart polygon because I was trying to isolate the problem with a larger shapefile. I repeated the steps you've written here, but am still get different areas after using `disaggregate` on `multi_part`. However, I now see that `disaggregate` creates two additional polygons that should be polygon holes.  So yes, you said it exactly, there is confusion with polygon holes. I'm not sure how to handle this or what is causing it, if you can offer any guidance. Now I know precisely what the problem is, thank you!

Comment: I have added some code. If that does not help perhaps you need to make your file available.

Comment: Thanks!  I have edited my question to add a link to the shapefile, and I've added a couple of images to make confusion with the holes more clear.